# Make the system message banner less distracting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, system-message

The SU system message has been distracting me *consistently,* and I'm not the only one:

> The one on SF is driving me freakin' nuts right now. To the point where I've quit checking in.
>     — [squillman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-add-the-ability-to-close-the-announcement-bar/64124#64124)

Rather than closing, dismissing, or merging the system message with other notifications, can it be toned down?  (Merging is definitely a mistake, but adding an option to close/dismiss has been [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-add-the-ability-to-close-the-announcement-bar).)

The toned-down colors could be applied only after the message is X days old (perhaps a week) in order to keep new/hot issues very visible (i.e. distracting).  This also prevents users both from accidentally closing and then missing the message, and from needing to see the message after they closed it but not knowing where to go (since it would still be visible and even in the exact same location).

Comment: How is this a duplicate of closing the system message?  I specifically excluded that.

Comment: I agree - on other sites it is very non-descript and didn't get in the way all that often. Possibly because they use softer colors. But the ones on SF and SU are way too in-your-face.

Comment: In your face is all the rage. After that, you forget you can even see something there. @gra

Comment: I forgot to mention it above, but, while this applies when designing colors for any site, SU is the only one bugging me at the moment.  Beta site colors and (IIRC) Meta's colors have been fine.

Comment: I would settle for this.  And build it in to the markup returned by the view instead of using jQuery.  Easily 2/3 of the annoyance is that the div pops in and shifts the layout when it does.  On every page load.