# Close button for "community moderator election is underway" notification?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enhance the behavior of the system-message bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-enhance-the-behavior-of-the-system-message-bar)

Since today evening I am seeing the notification "The Stack Overflow 2011 community moderator election is underway — nominations now being accepted."
Would it be possible to have close button for this notification so that once I read it I can click on the button to close it?

Comment: No.  It will haunt your days, and fuel your nightmares for 15 days, as it is written in the Book of JeffNJoel.

Comment: @Pollyanna Is that the book ends after [87 chapters](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/podcast-87/) because Joel was tired of hearing himself talk?

Comment: @George - No, you must be confusing it with another book.  This book will end in 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This notification will last for 48 hours, so all you need to do is wait.

Comment: Is this 48 hour window specific to the nomination notice, or is that a global window for all notifications?  A global 48 hour window would satisfy me as a solution for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-enhance-the-behavior-of-the-system-message-bar