# The nomination links have disappeared?

Tags: support, election, nominations

It seems than on all three SOFU sites the nomination links have disappeared, it is a bug or by design?

This was spotted [one hour ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/393463#393463) and they are still not visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jeff stated that the banner would only show for 48 hours.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75409/close-button-for-community-moderator-election-is-underway-notification/75421#75421)

You can still find them at https://stackoverflow.com/election

Comment: Confirmed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75409/close-button-for-community-moderator-election-is-underway-notification/75421#75421

Comment: The system messages have a maximum life of 48 hours.

Comment: Also, they're still on all of the meta sites.

Comment: Hmm, people who have not visited in those 48 hours will likely to miss the election if it's not somewhere prominently visible. Right?

Comment: @Bart, yes.  If they don't hear about it from other channels they will miss it.  There is a blog post about it.

Comment: @Justin, do you know if the other stages of the election (the Primary & Election itself, of course) will be announced for 48 again? Would be helpful for people with a memory like a sieve (me!).

Comment: @Bart, that I do not know.  I would assume that they would like to encourage voting.  So I'll bet that they will have a notification.  You could ask this in it's own question as 'support' or even 'feature request' if you really wanna know.

Comment: @Justin, yeah, I'll go ahead and ask the question myself. Cheers!