# Where can I find a link to community moderator election?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks, election

The notification bar with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/election) disappeared after 48h. From the SO frontpage on, where can I find a concrete link to the moderator elections without the need to peek in my browser history?

Comment: I agree that there should be a link. But I'll bet a beer Jeff is  going to turn it down with a snarky comment

Comment: Wasn't there just a post complaining about the notification bar. :)  Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: @RD01 true, but a link in the top menu might do. Having a notification bar all the time would really be annoying.

Comment: @pekka I don't disagree - dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75736/the-nomination-links-have-disappeared however.

Comment: @RD01: I am not asking where it is (I already linked it in my own question). I am asking where a concrete link is. How would one ever know about the progress in nominations without the need to bookmark it yourself or crawl in the browser history? Then I'm not talking about users who missed the notification bar because they were off for some days. This question is more in UX perspective. I find it poor tbh.

Comment: @balus perhaps I wasn't clear, I agree there should be a link.  I linked to a question that (links to another question) where Jeff states the notification is for 48 hours.  I'm not saying there shouldn't be a link, just that this isn't the first complaint about it.  I'm also not saying we should close this discussion about it :)

Comment: @RD01: I didn't complain that the notification bar disappeared after 48h. I just complain that there's no clear/concrete link anywhere for the case one would like to take a look again. I'd expect it to be subtly somewhere in the right column or maybe in the gray top bar.

Comment: @BalusC, it's REST. Quite honestly like you I was also surprised when the link disappeared and decided to take my chance and type `/election`. Nailed it from the first time :-)

Comment: @Darin: I knew the exact URL. I just play for the unaware enduser here.

Comment: @BalusC, I am one of the unaware users who was searching for the link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Too bad I can't downvote my own answers.

Comment: Taken care of for you chich!

Comment: @JNK: thanks! I see that this problem still manifests with the current election :(