# Should Stack Overflow support the Google Take Action campaign?

Tags: discussion, notification-bar, politics

I remember last year when congress was trying to pass the SOPA act and SO put a banner up to make people aware and stand against it. Well this year it seems to be happening again (or something similar):

[Google Take Action: Add Your Voice to Keep the Internet Free and Open](https://www.google.com/takeaction)

I was wondering if it is possible for SO/SE to do the same thing again with the banners to support our free internet?

Seems like [NDAA passed last week](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2012/01/02/president-obama-signed-the-national-defense-authorization-act-now-what/) and if our internet becomes censored and warrant-free spied upon, well, I am just gonna snap.

Comment: If Stack Overflow puts up a banner about US laws I couldn't care less about, I'm just gonna snap.

Comment: Did you snap last year when they did that? That's the only reason I posted this.. and really, you could care less about this? wow

Comment: Hm? Who did what last year? There was no banner for SOPA... Also, why should I care about this? Or any US law?

Comment: Yes, they did. And I think anyone should care about any freedom of speech impairments for any country.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about that [6 hour long system message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114203/why-has-the-sopa-banner-disappeared-from-the-site-header)... Right...

Comment: Title edited - I wasn't really asking to support the google campaign, but to do something similar, like a simple awareness message.

Comment: @Shredder: You're welcome to change the title again if you feel there's something that summarizes it better, but SE putting up a system message for it is basically SE supporting it. I only edited it because your previous title meant different things depending on how you read it.

Comment: @Yannis: This isn't even a US-specific law. If you read the Google Take Action page, the United States is actually not mentioned *anywhere*. The conference is between many governments around the globe, and the campaign is geared towards people across the globe protecting their free and open Internet.

Comment: @animuson I was talking about NDAA.

Comment: @Yannis Re: "puts up a banner about US laws" - The banner I'm proposing was not for NDAA... I should not have put that in the post. But if this internet censorship takes place, then people's awareness of such gov. corruption acts (such *as* NDAA) will be greatly hindered (and no SE ):

Comment: Perhaps then you should update your question and clarify _exactly_ what you are talking about. Are you aware what conference Google Take Action page is talking about? Do you have any idea about the agenda of the conference, or which countries are attending? What will the banner be about?

Comment: Wow, haters gonna hate

Comment: You are asking for a banner. And I'm simply asking: What will the banner be about? Also, are you proposing we have the banner for the full 11 days WCIT-12 will last?

Comment: Take the post for what it is. Close it for all I care. I tried. Sorry I don't have all the info or a precise implementation. That's what the `discussion` tag was for.

Comment: No, the sad thing is that you didn't. I'm sorry to be harsh, but hacktivism helps no one, if you honestly feel this is a serious issue, you owe it to yourself to approach it a bit more seriously. Do some research, find out _exactly_ what the campaign is about and come up with _concrete_ ideas.

Comment: Actually, I did. What do you think this is? It has to start somewhere. If somebody wants to take a better approach then by all means.

Comment: At least in the US judges can strike down laws that they deem to be unconstitutional - IOW a judge can strike down the NDAA law when it gets challenged in court.

Comment: I've gotten to the point where I automatically interpret *"haters gonna hate"* as *"I have no argument so I'm going to pretend the other guy is somehow defective"*. Don't do it.

Comment: Perhaps these sort of things could work as community ads? Though they are currently reserved for open source projects on SO, I see some of the smaller sites ([e.g. Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012)) have less strict policies about what community ads they allow.

Answer (score 12):

In general, I believe that SE should be apolitical.  Nothing will destroy your beloved sites faster than promoting political agendas of any sort.

The SOPA banner was a special case: SOPA would have affected SE and many other Internet sites' business model in a very direct way.  Having the banner up for a mere six hours was still extremely controversial.

Comment: Not to mention that WCIT-12 is a _conference_. People will gather and talk, no laws will (directly) come out of it. Are we going to put up a banner against _discussion_?

Comment: The whole thing sounds like a reasonable opportunity for a blog post, if anyone feels so inclined. But a banner would be a bit much imho.

Comment: @Bart The Programmers community blog would be ideal for this.

Comment: @Yannis: People *gathering* to *talk*? Ridiculous! Forget a banner, can't we just close the conference as "not constructive" or something?