# Where did the election notification bar go on SO?

Tags: support, notifications, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a link to community moderator election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76062/where-can-i-find-a-link-to-community-moderator-election)

The last to days there was a small yellow banner on SO that notified about the current moderator election. Now it's gone. Shouldn't the notification stay up until the election is over? Especially since there doesn't seem to be any other link to the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Jeff the notification was only designed to last 48 hours: [Close button for "community moderator election is underway" notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75409/close-button-for-community-moderator-election-is-underway-notification)

I agree a link to the page somewhere else would be nice, but I think the reason the notification bar is only up for a couple days is because most of the people who care about it have already voted because they login every day.

Comment: I was sort of hoping it went away after I voted; I always find these notifications annoying by taking up valuable top 'o the screen real estate.

Comment: @Jay, yea I read somewhere else on Meta that it was "dumb" notification that did not know if you voted or not.  I did see it before and after I voted.

Comment: If it is assumed that everybody who cares has already voted, then the election should just be closed. Keeping it open but not telling the people that haven't voted about it seems pointless...

Comment: Make sure you tell that to the guy who runs a tight second place! I would say it does not matter. It happens once a year. I don't think a couple days makes any difference. @sth

Answer (score 5):

The mandatory bar is only displayed for 48 hours - this one cannot be dismissed.

However, one notice was inserted into everyone's notification bar (the one that tells you if you've gained a new badge, etc) so that if one did not log in during the mandatory bar period, one still gets notice about the election.

The reason the mandatory bar is only on for 48 hours is that people complain about not being able to get rid of it.

The reason to have a mandatory bar for at least 48 hours is to make certain those most active users are very strongly encouraged to participate, whereas it's easy to get rid of the notice bar message thinking one might get to it later, but then forgetting to do so.  The mandatory bar is somewhat in-your-face.

Personally I'd prefer a slightly different mix: The mandatory bar appears on all accounts, is not dismissable, and does so for the whole period of the election, but only for those users who have not completed their vote who are eligible to vote.

Comment: +1 This certainly sounds like the intended behavior.