# Election link missing from TeX-SE main site

Tags: support, bug, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the election notification bar go on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77319/where-did-the-election-notification-bar-go-on-so)

(cross-posted on meta.TeX-SE) [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/964/election-link-missing-from-the-main-site)

I noticed yesterday that the election link is no longer featured on the [TeX-SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). Is this [status-by-design]? As far as I remember, this link has been present on all SE sites that underwent election until their conclusion.

The link is still present on meta.TeX, though.

Comment: This is by design. Election notice only lasts for 48 hours after the start of each phase on the parent site, but you'll notice that you still have one on the Meta site. If your pro tems are up for it, they can re-enable the system message, but this is typically discouraged. Keep in mind, also, that during the final election phase, there is also a pop up banner given to *all* eligible voters to pester them, and it does not time out like the system message does.

Comment: It was closed as a duplicate, but I'm going to vote this towards [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77319/where-did-the-election-notification-bar-go-on-so) rather than the parent, since this one actually explains the scenario. Though, everything of relevance is in my comment above, so this is just a formality.

Comment: @Grace Note: Quick question about the voting stage.  If someone is eligible to vote and hasn't yet voted, do they always see the banner?  I notice that it isn't there for me on the main site but is on meta - but I've voted so it may not be a reliable data point.  If *no-one* can see it on the main site then I'll stick up a new one, but if you can confirm that those still to vote can see it then I'll leave well enough alone.  Thanks!

Comment: @Grace: Sorry, I hadn't clicked through to the duplicate.  There it does seem that it has gone even for those who haven't voted yet.  So if I don't hear otherwise, I'll assume that it is gone.

Comment: @Andrew I left you some messages to explain in the TeX, LaTeX, and Friends chat room on chat.stackexchange. If you have any further questions, just buzz me in there, mmkay? ♪