# Can we make 'memorial' banners clickable to dismiss?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please enhance the behavior of the system-message bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-enhance-the-behavior-of-the-system-message-bar)
>   [Can we get an option to hide system messages?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/can-we-get-an-option-to-hide-system-messages)

In certain environments I have very limited screen real estate and would like to be able to dismiss the memorial banner** in much the same way as I'm able to dismiss the notification banners when badges are earned, etc.

Is there a way to do this currently that I'm missing, or would this be a possible addition to the feature set?

** In case its not clear what I'm referring to, currently its the Steve Jobs banner but I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that this is a first class member of SO's framework and will be generated when other luminaries pass on or for other comparable big events

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/can-we-get-an-option-to-hide-system-messages, which was closed as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/please-enhance-the-behavior-of-the-system-message-bar.

Comment: Unrelated, but boy howdy does wording have a big impact on feature request score!

Comment: Ah thanks, for some reason those didn't show up as potential dups when was trying to figure out if it was one...guess its down to the phrasing

Comment: I feel a little bad for NullUserException right now

Comment: Please see my GreaseMonkey script for doing this in firefox. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/allow-us-an-exit-hatch-to-dismiss-the-system-message-notification-bar/108576#108576

Comment: For the record, I haven't seen any reason to expect that system messages will frequently be used for this purpose. So "will be generated when other luminaries pass on or for other comparable big events" is probably false. The messages are normally only used for important notifications directly relevant to the site.