# Is there a way to remove StackOverflow notice message

Tags: support, system-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow us an exit hatch to dismiss the system message notification bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/allow-us-an-exit-hatch-to-dismiss-the-system-message-notification-bar)

I would like to remove SO notice message because I have read all about it, and I don't want it there.

Example:
[image]

I have read it all, and I don't want it there, or that functionality doesn't exists.

Comment: You would think after the Steve Jobs incident you would be very careful about using the system message for events such as these.  I truly think that those message bars should ONLY be used for system notifications such as serious downtime.  And I would only use them in rare cases.  Stuff like SOPA and Jobs death should be the notification bar (jquery) that has the 'X' symbol allowing me to close it.  In addition, I don't really care about the event.

Comment: I don't get it... why do these messages annoy people so much?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen - Because they are uhm annoying...

Comment: because its background is yellow and every time I reload SO i see it and always trying to read if its something new.

Comment: -1, I really like it, how it is showing. Telling us to and reminding us.

Comment: So you -1 because you don't like my Question ?

Comment: Moderator closed this question, and there is no answer anywhere, duplicated question looks like Forum posts, everyone is giving theirs opinion. No direct answer.

Comment: I also find this largely irrelevant. Changed my user stylesheet from `#system-message { opacity: 0.5; }` to `{ display: none; }` now. Only user-specific notification bars for me.

Comment: @TriLLi - I think the duplicate means this has been brought up in the past with a prior post discussing a possible "feature" to remove it.  Short answer is you cannot remove it - unless you write up some dirty lil script - and that isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: How is this an annoyance? If this bill passes, there may not be a Stack Overflow anymore, and certainly no notice messages to complain about.

Comment: You can't remove it unless you jump two days into the future. The other question is asking for a way to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to remove it.

You can remove it easily with some userscript.

To get you started on that script, the message DOM ID is `system-message`

Comment: I know that, but it would be nice if just this one is disabled, I want to see next one.

Comment: @TriLLi next what? There is only one.

Comment: Yes, but if I use grease  monkey to execute my script each time stackoverflow is opened, then it will remove also new one. Get it?

Comment: im sure you can greasemonkey up a `x`