# Add support for user specific banners

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be good to support displaying banners based on a user's properties: banners only displayed to users with a certain privilege or reputation

For example it would be nice if you could display a different banner for the election to users who don't have sufficient reputation to vote.

Comment: Do you have any other examples of use other than the election one?

Comment: Suggestion: No way to get rid of the "Read the FAQ" banner until the user hits 20 rep.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/allow-us-an-exit-hatch-to-dismiss-the-system-message-notification-bar